# Keeping a Running Total from a Separate Table

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm hoping someone can help me with a script I'm trying to create.

Basically, I have two tables on two different sheets. The first table is a list of every single item my company carries, and then three blank columns for each store.

The second table is for the employees to type in when they're low on something, there's actually one per store but I'll create three separate scripts for each store. I use data validation from the first table so that the values are always the same.

What I want to do is create a script to count every time that item is marked as low. I can't use a regular formula for this, because the list gets updated and then cleared out when the item is no longer low. What I'm hoping to do, is put a button on the sheet (I can handle that part,) where they type in the items, highlight it(to make it the active range), and then run the script. All the script has to do is match the items on the two sheets, and then increase the value on the first sheet by 1. The part I can't figure out is how to match the values on both sheets. Any help? :)

Here is a sample spreadsheet. I've cleared out all irrelevant rows so there's no confusion. I've put some sample numbers in the first sheet, those are the numbers I want to be increased by 1 when a store marks that they're low on it again.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ox2qonPbJEliuarbQ6pIrSJLcCROhN6Y5l7K-BQj0zw/edit?usp=sharing

This is what I have right now. Obviously, the if section doesn't work. I can't figure out a way to match the two ranges properly.

```
function HTLOW() {
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var DS = ss.getSheetByName("Data");
  var sheetDS=DS
  var maxRows = sheetDS.getMaxRows();
 var HS = ss.getSheetByName("Store 1");

  var Lrange = HS.getActiveRange();
  var Nrange = sheetDS.getRange(3, 2, maxRows);
  var Drange = sheetDS.getRange(3, 3, maxRows);

  var Lvalue = Lrange.getValues();
  var Dvalue = Drange.getValues();
  var Nvalue = Nrange.getValues();
  for (var row in Lvalue) {
    var Lcelldata = Lvalue[row][0];
    var Dcelldata = Dvalue[row][0];
    var Ncelldata = Nvalue[row][0];

    if ( Lcelldata != Ncelldata) {
      Dvalue[row][0] = Dcelldata + 1;
    }

  Drange.setValues(Dvalue);
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the error log?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! There actually isn't an error log, as what's there currently does "work." It just doesn't work the way I intend it to. Right now it's just randomly adjusting some numbers that I can't seem to find a pattern to. I just can't get the two ranges to match each other like I want them to.